# How to add firebase IOS SDK to a project?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sdk

Im using Xcode 13 and package manager. I try to add from file > Swift Packages -> Add package dependency -> Select project -> type in url of the firebase SDK. My project does not show up in the list.

Comment: Try taking a look at these docs: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/08/firebase-swift-package-manager.html#:~:text=Open%20your%20iOS%20project%20in,to%20use%20in%20your%20project

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

It is hard to understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Try rephrasing your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.